# Rails 4 render js.erb files

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

When access an url, direct from browser I want to render a js.erb file. The following code worked for render the js and not the html file. But the alert is not showed, the code is printed as text in the page. How can I render the file and get js executed?

**routes.rb**

get '/users/:id', to: 'users#show', defaults: { format: 'js' }

**users/show.js.erb**

alert("teste");

Answer (score 0):

The `users/show.js.erb` is just `javascript` code but it was not placed in a `html script` tag so it will not be execute.

Comment: When I render the *.js.erb by link (:remote => true), the code in the file is injected in the page, so it works, right? How can I do the same when I load the page? Can I do that with an yield for example?

Comment: You are right for the `:remote=>true`. I think you can't do that, instead you should render a html page with `window.ready="your js code"` by `script` tag or add `onload` attribute in the `body tag`.
Hope this help!